# Compiling Error On BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, environment-variables, compiler-errors

I have done simple java app for blackberry, while building am getting following error.

```
"Building Hisantosh
C:\BlackBerryJDE4.5.0\bin\rapc.exe  -quiet import=..\lib\net_rim_api.jar codename=Hisantosh Hisantosh.rapc warnkey=0x52424200;0x52525400;0x52435200
"C:\Documents and Settings\Santosh\My Documents\Downloads\greetingscreen.java"
"C:\Documents and Settings\Santosh\My Documents\Downloads\helloworld.java"
I/O Error: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Error while building project "
```

I have set all path variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have your environment variables setup, you'll need to set up 'PATH' environment variable, the path will be something like: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin; depending on where you have installed your JDK files.

If this is setup, check out this [link from Blackberry knowledge centre](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/Support_-_I_O_Error_CreateProcess.html?nodeid=800760&vernum=0)